# C++ Map Question

Tags: c++, dictionary, multimap

I'm working on my C++ assignment about soccer and I encountered a problem with map.

My problem that I encountered is that when I stored 2 or more "midfielders" as the key, even the cout data shows different, but when I do a multiplication on the 2nd ->second value, it "adds up" the first ->second value and multiply with it.

E.g.

```
John   midfielder   1
Steven midfielder   3
```

I have a program that already reads in the playerPosition. So the map goes like this:

```
John 1 (Key, Value)
Steven 3 (Key, Value)

if(playerName == a->first && playerPosition == "midfielder")
{
    cout << a->second*2000 << endl;   //number of goals * $2000
}
```

So by right, the program should output:

```
2000
6000
```

But instead, I'm getting

```
2000
8000
```

So, I'm assuming it adds the 1 to 3 (resulting in 4) and multiplying with 2000, which is totally wrong...

I tried cout a->first and a->second in the program and I get:

```
John 1
Steven 3
```

But after the multiplication, it's totally different.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

Edit:
Ok, I try. I'm actually calculating the bonus for each position field. I have already inserted the field data into the map and here is the actual codes.

```
multiset<string, less<string> >::iterator q, p = myset.begin();
q = myset.begin()++;

while (p != myset.end())
{        
        if(*p == *q)
        {
            currentScore = (int) myset.count(*p);
            mymap.insert(pair<string, int>(*p, currentScore));
        }
        else if(*p != *q && topScore == 0)
        {
            topScore = (int) myset.count(*q);
            topScorer = *q;
            mymap.insert(pair<string, int>(*q, topScore));
        }
        else if(*p != *q)
        {
            currentScore = (int) myset.count(*p);
            mymap.insert(pair<string, int>(*p, currentScore));

            if(currentScore > topScore)
            {
                topScore = currentScore;
                topScorer = *p;
                mymap.insert(pair<string, int>(*p, topScore));
            }
        }
        p++;
}



map<string, int>::iterator a = mymap.begin();
while(a != mymap.end())
{
if(playerName == a->first && playerPosition == "goalkeeper")
{
   goalkeepers++;
   goalkeeperBonus+=(a->second*5000);
   sumBonus+=goalkeeperBonus;
}
else if(playerName == a->first && playerPosition == "midfielder")
{
   midfielders++;
   midfielderBonus+=(a->second*2000);
   sumBonus+=midfielderBonus;
}
a++;
}
```

The test data is:

```
Score: 3-1 
Ben
Steven
Ben
Score: 2-0 
John
Steven
Score: 1-0 
Ben
Score: 0-0
Score: 1-1 
Cole
Score: 1-2
Ben
Score: 3-0
Cole
Steven
Ben
```

I tried to cout during the while loop and I got the output as:

```
Ben 5
Cole 2
John 1
Steven 3
```

This should be the correct output with Steven having 3 goals. But I'm getting 4, added with John's. Is there any way to assign the bonus to the a->first which is the player's name?

Comment: Have you tried other inputs like 7 and 5?

Comment: I just tried to assign John to 7 and Steven to 5. But it still adds up the first value to the second and multiply. I tried putting the 3rd "midfielder" and assign a value to it. It adds up the first and second value to it too...

Comment: Post the minimal code that demonstrates the issue.  Many times people find the issue using this technique before posting. :-)

Comment: Are `playerName` / `playerposition` std::string, or char*?  If char*, you have to use `strcmp()` (or change them to std::string)

Comment: They are strings, not char*...

Comment: @Wallace: Please format your code by selecting them, then click the 101010 button on the toolbar.

Comment: `midfielderBonus+=(a->second*2000)` <-- Do you know what `+=` does?  You're summing all the bonuses.  So the initial value would be 2000, then the next one would be (2000 + 6000), which is exactly what you're seeing.  Is this the value you're printing?

Comment: @KennyTM: Sorry, I'm new here. Just formatted my codes using 101010 button. Thanks for telling me.

@Dennis: This might be the cause of it... But I'm calculating other bonuses for each midfielders too. So I'm using += to add this bonus to the midfielderBonus. Is there any way to assign each midfielderBonus to each midfielder player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`midfielderBonus+=(a->second*2000);`

So that += means it will accumulate the data. i assume you are forgetting a `midfielderBonus=0` at some point when you move on to the next player. Kind of hard to tell as the code snippet you included doesn't show the initialization of the bonus variables.

Comment: I will solved the problem. The problem lies with the +=, as what many earlier others have said. I assigned this particular bonus to another variable and compute the overall bonus by adding every other bonus together.

Thanks for the help. You guys are great :)

Comment: If the problem is solved, you might want to close the question. Or you may continue to get answers.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I close this question? I just started using this community.

Comment: There is a check box outline next to each answer. You can click on it to accept the answer. Or if you solved the question yourself, you can post your solution as an Answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in your included code that would cause what you're getting.  There's of course obviously more going on that might explain it, especially since your if should seemingly only apply to one player.

Comment: My codes are rather long, so I'm not sure if I can paste them all here. Or perhaps I could upload my script so any helpful souls can see what's wrong with it? Just wanted to ask if anyone encountered a similar problem and any solutions.

Comment: Here are my codes zipped up with the test data and expected results.

http://www.mediafire.com/?kzyuizlgi4y

I'm already more than halfway through my assignment and I'm stuck at this part which I can't get it right.

If uploading of files are not appropriate, let me know and I'll take it down.

Comment: You don't need to provide all the code, just the important bits.  Definitely provide your map definition, and the code that generates your `a` iterator.  Skip the map population for now.